Question about polynomials, their degrees and their real roots.
$A(x)$, $B(x)$ and $C(x)$ be polynomials,and at least $1$ of degree $3$,and $1$ of $2$. They all have real koefficients.
Show:If $A(x)^2+B(x)^2=C(x)^2$,then $1$ Polyn. of degree $3$ has only real roots.
I got this question asked from a friend of mine. I got, that $C(x)$ and $B(x)$ have to be of degree $3$, but I can not further simplify the question.
Thank you in advance.

are $A,B,C$ supposed to have real coefficients only or are they general complex polynomials?

Real coefficients only.

Since $A^2=(C-B)(C+B)$ and $A^2$ has degree $4$ it follows that one of $C-B, C+B$ has degree $1$ and one has degree $3$ and since the problem is invariant when dividing by a nonzero constant we can assume both $B,C$ monic and then $C-B$ degree $1$. Also the root of $C-B$ is a root of $C+B$ too (as is a root of $A^2$ so double root) hence a root of $C,B$ and is real ($C-B$ degree $1$ real coefficients) - let's call it $a$ so $C=(x-a)(x^2+bx+c), B(x)=(x-a)(x^2+bx+d)$ (since $C-B$ linear) and $C-B=(c-d)(x-a)$ so $c \ne d$
But since then $A$ has the real root $a$, its other root is real too, so $C+B=2(x-a)(x^2+bx+\frac{c+d}{2})$ has only real roots hence $b^2-2(c+d) \ge 0$ and then if say $c < d$ we get $b^2-4c>0$ so $C$ has three real roots, while if $c>d$ we have $B$ with three real roots and we are done!
